# Iphone Web view inside scroll view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a small application with some detail controller. Detail controller is a web view put inside scroll view:
Here is a code of detail view controller:

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page
```

{

```
if (page < 0)
    return;
if (page >= detailTotalJobs)
    return;

// replace the placeholder if necessary
SearchJobDetailWebViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
{



    NSLog(@"Vytvaram web controller: %d", page + 1);

    if (detailJobIndex == page) {

        controller = [[SearchJobDetailWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchJobDetailWebViewController" bundle:nil page:page url:detailExportUrl];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];

    } else if (detailJobIndex + 1 == page) {

        controller = [[SearchJobDetailWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchJobDetailWebViewController" bundle:nil page:page url:detailNextExportUrl];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];

    } else {

        [self performSelector:@selector(downloadData:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:page] afterDelay:0.1];
        //[self downloadData:[NSNumber numberWithInt:page]];

        controller = [[SearchJobDetailWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchJobDetailWebViewController" bundle:nil page:page url:nextArray.exportUrl];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];

    }

}

// add the controller's view to the scroll view
if (controller.view.superview == nil)
{

    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    controller.view.frame = frame;
    [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];

    //NSDictionary *numberItem = [self.contentList objectAtIndex:page];
    //controller.numberImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[numberItem valueForKey:ImageKey]];
    //controller.myLabel.text = @"Test";
}
```

}

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
```

{
    // We don't want a "feedback loop" between the UIPageControl and the scroll delegate in
    // which a scroll event generated from the user hitting the page control triggers updates from
    // the delegate method. We use a boolean to disable the delegate logic when the page control is used.
    if (pageControlUsed)
    {
        // do nothing - the scroll was initiated from the page control, not the user dragging
        return;
    }

```
// Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
pageControl.currentPage = page;

NSString *detailTitleText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d / %d", page + 1, detailTotalJobs];
[self setTitle:detailTitleText];
//[detailTitleText release];

// load the visible page and the page on either side of it (to avoid flashes when the user starts scrolling)
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page - 1];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page];
[self loadScrollViewWithPage:page + 1];

// A possible optimization would be to unload the views+controllers which are no longer visible
```

}

Code inspired by Apple page control.

Problem is here:

```
if (detailJobIndex == page) {

        controller = [[SearchJobDetailWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchJobDetailWebViewController" bundle:nil page:page url:detailExportUrl];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];

    } else if (detailJobIndex + 1 == page) {

        controller = [[SearchJobDetailWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchJobDetailWebViewController" bundle:nil page:page url:detailNextExportUrl];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];

    } else {

        [self performSelector:@selector(downloadData:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:page] afterDelay:0.1];
        //[self downloadData:[NSNumber numberWithInt:page]];

        controller = [[SearchJobDetailWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchJobDetailWebViewController" bundle:nil page:page url:nextArray.exportUrl];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];

    }
```

First part and second part of if work correctly, because I have data for first web view and for second web view.

But last part of if have a problem. when I scroll from second web view to third web view, scroll view show blank page. Next pages work correctly.
Where is problem, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a breakpoint in debug mode on the braces.
Is controller nil ?
Check your custom init method.

Does it return nil if there is a problem ?

```
[self = super initWithNibName..................];
if (!self) return nil;

// some inits

return self;
```

If this is done and controller is nil, check your URL, and try it into a web browser. Does it showsup ?

How do you fill your webView ? Is there an error returned when filling it ? No encoding problem returned ?

Well, some code would help, but these indications are the most common problems you can have.

Comment: First I call this method: [self performSelector:@selector(downloadData:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:page] afterDelay:0.1]; for download data then a I create web view controller. Problem is When I log this two method that: First log was creation of web view controller and then was call a download data method (controller get url as null), but why ...

Comment: I need download next data in background ... When user start app download first two web pages (this works fine ...) when scroll from first to second app must download the next page in background (here is problem), because third page is empty and data of third page are on court page ... next pages works fine ...

Comment: Why do you delay the call. That can be the cause of you problem. Why don't you just call the method ? The controller is created before your datas are loaded. 0.1 s, it's huge in computing time. DownloadData is called async so your controller is created before the download is called

Comment: because when I call only method, this method block guy while data downloading ...

Comment: Your just blocking it 0.1s later.... You should then convert your call as an async (web ?) call or send it to another thread, AND make your webView able to load datas after it is created. Check every 0.1 s if the data container is null, and if not populate the webView. Don't forget to put some timeout in case the data could not be loaded.